# Does Google container registry support docker remote API V2

Tags: docker-registry, google-container-registry

I'm storing my docker images in my private Google Container Registry and I want to interact with the images through registry V2 APIs, such as getting tags of an image (`/v2/:imageName/tags/list`). I believe that it is supported, according to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/?hl=en_US&_ga=1.115327566.832874202.1434685013.) But I cannot found related documentation. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is (including that endpoint).  You should be able to interact with it after authenticating in the standard way outlined [here](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/auth/token.md).

Feel free to reach out on gcr-contact@google.com also if you have any troubles.

Answer (score 3):

Just got answer from google support, hope this helps others:

```
$ export NAME=project-id/image
$ export BEARER=$(curl -u _token:$(gcloud auth print-access-token) https://gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository:$NAME:pull | cut -d'"' -f 10)
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" https://gcr.io/v2/$NAME/tags/list
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Quyen Nguyen Tuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533440/quyen-nguyen-tuan)'s answer, if you don't want to have to use `gcloud` at all, create a service account, pass the username `_json_key` and use the service account's json key as the password instead:

```
$ export NAME=project-id/image
$ export BEARER=$(curl -u "_json_key:$(cat path/to/json/key.json)" "https://gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository:$NAME:pull" | cut -d'"' -f 10)
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" https://gcr.io/v2/$NAME/tags/list
```

and remember to prefix appropriately (e.g. `eu.gcr.io`) if that's where your repo is.