# Is there Google cloud APIs to manage containerised images?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

Requirement is to copy the images from one GCR to another GCR and tag the images. I see only google cloud SDK and console options. This require to install SDK and initialise it. Looking for APIs to perform these operations.

Comment: Why would you want to move the images? You could simply use a service account to access the GCR... Or maybe that isn't the question..

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097445/8016720

Comment: This one too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34037256/8016720

Comment: It helps. Thanks John Hanley.